# Make a HTTP GET request from iOS device from background task

Tags: ios, swift, http-get, background-task

I want to perform a scheduled background task from iOS device for perform an Http GET API call to my backend server.
I went through iOS background tasks [documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), and I found out Background fetch will be a good solution for this problem. But according to the documentation they are not allowing to schedule these kind of tasks in background. I want to know that is there any work around for this?

Comment: Is it possible to call http GET or POST in background?